# Python3 replacing Python errors with different output

Tags: error-handling

I have one issue that I would like fixed but I am not able to. I have a small script that requires SSH key to work properly. When the SSH key is not properly loaded, the following Python Error appears:

> SSH: Permission denied (publickey). Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/path/to/python3file.py", line 117, in 
> func.func_check()   File "/path/to/python3file.py", line 18, in func_check
> ssh = subprocess.check_output(["ssh", "-p22", "{}@{}".format("user", self.host), command])   File
> "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py",
> line 411, in check_output
> return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,   File
> "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py",
> line 512, in run
> raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args, subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ssh', '-p22', 'user@chost',
> ' script func user']' returned non-zero exit status 255.

Basically, I want to replace the entire error code from the above with something more user-friendly like:

`Please import SSH key`

Is that even possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Try Except](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp), and specify the type of error you are handling. In this case it is `IOError`.

```
try:
    print('my code here')
except IOError, e:
    print('Please import SSH key')
```